# Why json change my properties names class

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I use ASP.NET core
I have a class
[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aojgX.png)
And when i run the project the result is different and my properties names is not same like my properties in c# class
[see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aojgX.png)

Comment: Please edit in the relevant pieces of code and json as *code* in your question and not as images.

Comment: And we don't see your class since you linked to the same picture twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pascal Case
Just we add this code in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
            });
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

there are two ContractResolver for MvcCore JsonOptions(PascalCasing and camelCasing). if you want CamelCase, must set your MVC MiddleWare like:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
...
services.AddMvc()
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
});
...
}
```